# What is the difference between my own hot_labels and creating hotlabels with functions?

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I am new to python and machine learning, since I have been learning day by day. I want to clear somethings, and this time about my labels. I have 2004 classes to classify from. And I am building labels manually from filenames. Like below

```
import numpy as np

path = "D:/data/image/1/1/asas1231231231.jpg"

label = np.zeros(2004)

# The line to read the 4th index from path and converting it into integer and then pass it on to the array to have the label
label[int(path.rsplit('/')[4]) - 1 ] = 1

# Which gives me
print(label[0])
1.0
```

Now I have file names till 2004 and at every iteration of reading images I am also making labels in the label and then appending them in the list like

```
training_labels = []

training_labels.append(label)
```

But after doing some research about labels I came to know about np_utils.to_categorical

```
np_utils.to_categorical(1,2004)
```

gives me

```
array([[1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

My question is what is the difference between both of them? 
Can anyone please explain me.
I also print the shape for my one it was

(2004,)

And with np_utils I get

(1,2004)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some confusion what "hot-label" really means. I assume you are referring to "one hot encoding" which is usually used to encode categorical variables in one hot encoded features ([see also here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26578/one-hot-encoding-of-target-space)). For example, if you have a variable men / women, you could represent this variable by a 0 for a man and a 1 for a women. This is maybe the regression perspective but for your training labels it essentially works the same way. In your code it looks like you are using the "raw" numbers as labels. The inherent problem here is (in classification) that normally the classes do not relate to each other. Assume your labels are red, green and yellow. In your aproach you would map them to the classes 1,2 and 3. One of the problems with that approach is that the ordering does not make sense, e.g. why is yellow (3) higher than red (1)? And why is the distance between red (1) and green (2) smaller than between red (1) and yellow(3)?

To avoid these kind of problems you encode your class by one-hot vectors. Have a look at the output from:

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
np_utils.to_categorical([0, 1,2], 2004)
>>array([[1., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

You will see that the to_categorical function actually starts the classes with 0. The shape is (3, 2004) because I input 3 different classes *([0, 1, 2])* and provided the number of classes with the second argument *2004*. Each of these vectors of length 2004 represents **a single class**. Depending on the position of the 1 in the vector the classes are defined. Note that each vector is unique for a class.

Lastly, have a look at some examples from the scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder).

That all being said, it might be useful to think if you really want to use the years as classes (classification) or numerical features (regression). This I cannot tell you.

HTH